# Iterate a JSON object and appendChild to DIV

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

I have a JSON object eg:

```
{ Naam: "bert", Achternaam: "Kopers"}
```

I would like to render this to a DIV element on my HTML page. It should look like this:

```
   <div id = "contents>
        <div class="setting-label">
            Naam
        </div>
        <div class="setting-value">
            bert    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="setting-row">
            <div class="setting-label">
                AchterNaam
            </div>
            <div class="setting-value">
                kopers  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Preferably I would like to this without innerHTML. So with appendChild. How does the code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```js
onload = function() {
      var person = {Naam: "Bert", Achternaam: "Kopers"};
      var contents = document.getElementById("contents");

      for(var key in person) {
        var personDiv = document.createElement("div");
      
        var div1 = document.createElement("div");
        var text1 = document.createTextNode(key);
        div1.appendChild(text1);
        
        var div2 = document.createElement("div");
        var text2 = document.createTextNode(person[key]);
        div2.appendChild(text2);
        
        personDiv.appendChild(div1);
        personDiv.appendChild(div2);
        
        contents.appendChild(personDiv);
      }
}
```

```html
<div id="contents"></div>
```

Will give you an HTML output of:

```html
<div id="contents">
  <div>
    <div>Naam</div>
    <div>Bert</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Achternaam</div>
    <div>Kopers</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. This works. I'm wondering if I could use a function to make it cleaner/simpler

Comment: Of course, you can! You can put this code in a function, say, `loadPerson()`, and then call this function in the `onload = function()` function.

Comment: Also, if you want to push it further, you could make a function that creates a `div` element and puts some text in it, and then call it to create `div1` and `div2`